# Laravel Storage facade asset() with wrong URL generation

Tags: php, laravel

I've been working on my project and just can't get it about Laravel Storage, specifically, `visibility : public` state of storage and its URL.

I do my uploaded file save via `$filename = $file->store('mpmlimages', 'public');`

From what I understand, when I put this `$filename` at `asset()` helper function, then I get my file URL.

In the current directory structure,

```
projectroot_folder
    |-- storage <-- this is actual storage, right?
    |       |--app
    |           |--public
    |                |--mpmlimages <-- this is file location
    |--public
          |--storage (symlink to storage\app\public) <-- it has shortcut icon.. I believe it's what laravel said simbolic link
```

**Fails to work if**
I use `asset($filename)`, I got `http://localhost:8000/mpmlimages/{GENERATED_FILENAME}.png`

**Works if**
Manually changing the above URL to `http://localhost:8000/storage/mpmlimages/{GENERATED_FILENAME}.png`

...WHY?!?!?!?!?!? I can't understand what I've missed.

Comment: Why not use the [storage_path](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-storage-path) helper to get actual files from the storage folder? Assets are images and icons used for your webpage specifically while storage could be for user uploads etc.

Comment: Those images are actually user upload image. It's not icon but maybe some sort of user character image. Also I don't even understand what is difference between `get actual file` and `using asset()`.. Is there any helpful keyword on this?

The reason why I'm doing this question is actually I can't understand first word. `Why not use the storage_path helper`... Is asset bad? ...

Comment: Thanks to all. I now understand what's different between asset and storage_path , especially regards to Borisu's answer. Still not correctly understand what exactly happend during storing file but I think I got the concept of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to prepend storage to the asset call:

```
asset("storage/{$filename}")
```

This way you don't have to create any symbolic links (besides the one you already have).
To answer the original question: calling `$file->store` will use the public disk. If you check your config files you'll notice that the root of the public disk is `'root' => storage_path('app/public')`, so that's why your files land in the `storage/app/public` folder.

Furthermore as a client you should only be able to access files in the public folder, hence the symbolic link to `storage`. That's the reason you don't use `storage_path()` as it will expose the webserver structure, instead of making a url the client can use. Example:

- `asset('storage/{$filename}')` results in `https:/server.com/storage/file.png`
- `storage_path($filename)` results in `/var/www/server/storage/app/public/file.png`

Answer (score 1):

That is due to the fact that `asset()` will point to `public` folder.
By creating a `symbolic link` from `storage` to `public` and using `asset()` you still need to tell laravel which of the folder/files in public you wish to access.

In you case is your `symbolic` link `which will restructure the path to`storage\app\public`;

If you do  a `symbolic link` from `storage\app\public\mpmlimages` to `public\mpmlimages` you can keep as `asset('mpmlimages/<your img>')`

**What I think your symlink structure is**

```
root
 |--public
 |    |--**S**storage (storage\app\public)
 |
 |--storage
       |--app
           |--public
                |--mpmlimages
                      |--img1.png
                      |--img2.jpeg
                      |-- etc
```

**What your symlink should be in order for you to drop storage**

```
root
  |--public
  |     |--**S**mpmlimages(storage\app\public\mpmlimages)
  |
  |--storage
        |--app
            |--public 
                  |--mpmlimages    
                        |--img1.png
                        |--img2.jpeg
                        |-- etc
```

**Legend:**

**S** -> As a Symlink indicator

To achieve this symlink relation, run:

```
ln -s storage/app/public/mpmlimages public/mpmlimages
```

Then if your `$filename` contains `mpmlimages/<img>`, all you need is:

```
asset($filename);
```

Comment: Thanks to reply. What your explain is when I using `asset()`, it should be like `asset('mpmlimages/{GENERATED_FILENAME}.png');`

However, in my code, `$filename` is already `mpmlimages/{GENERATED_FILENAME}.png`.

Comment: If your symlink is created with the pointer like I explained above, then yes ^^

Comment: I will create a structure on my answer to better view this problem, bear with me a sec! :)

Comment: @gatesPlan let me know if it makes more sense and if it helps! :)